# stage size for android on air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, stage

I've built an AS3 game with a stage size of 480 by 800, but I still get small margins on the top and bottom. I haven't made any coding relating to screen size cause I understand that 480x800 is the screen size that should fit exactly to the samsung 3 and 4 screen. I don't need it to fit other screens at the moment nor do I need it to orient (just portrait).
I read that the screen ratio is 9:16 so I tried with a stage of 422x750 but I still got margins!
How do I get rid of these margins? Is there a stage size that would fit the screen without coding or do I have to put some code for that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `stage.fullScreenWidth` and `stage.fullScreenHeight`. These 2 properties work alright for me both on Android and iOS (unlike stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight).